# Coloring number with this polygon

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

[image]

I ended up 3 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 96. 
But it was wrong.
How can you find out coloring vertices in this polygon?

Comment: are you asking how many ways are there to 3-color this polygon?

Comment: @gt6989b Yes.  I ended up 96 ways to color it, but it was wrong.

Comment: Assume you started at the left side and follow clockwise. The vertex at the right side doesn't have 2 possible colors, since its 2 neighbourgs have already used 2 colors.

Comment: Vertex 4 could have two possible colors, since vertices 1 and 3 could be the same color.  You have to add separate scenarios depending on whether vertices 1 and 3 are identically or differently colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I assume that you have 3 different colors and that connected vertices cannot have the same color.)*

Say that we have three different colors: R, G and B.

Step 1) Pick any color for the leftmost vertex, say R (3 different choices).

Step 2) Pick any color for the rightmost vertex, say G (2 different choices).

Step 3) Consider two bottom vertices: there are only 3 acceptable combinations of colors: GB, GR and BR (3 different choices).

Step 4) Consider two top vertices: again, there are only 3 acceptable combinations of colors: GB, GR and BR (3 different choices).

So the total number of colorings is $3\times2\times3\times3=54$.